# Volatile function

Tags: c++, c, volatile

**Summary**: What does the keyword `volatile` do when applied to a function declaration in C and in C++?

**Details**:

I see that it's possible to compile a function that is marked as `volatile`.  However, I'm not sure what compiler optimization (if any) this prevents.  For instance I created the following test case:

```
volatile int foo() {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  int total = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    total += foo();
  }

  return total;
}
```

When I compile with `clang -emit-llvm -S -O3 test.c` (gcc would also work but the llvm IR is more readable in my opinion) I get:

```
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

define i32 @foo() #0 {
  ret i32 1
}

define i32 @main() #0 {
  ret i32 100
}
```

So obviously the compiler was able to optimize away the calls to function `foo()` so that `main()` returns a constant, even though `foo()` is marked as `volatile`.  So my question is whether `volatile` does anything at all when applied to a function declaration in terms of limiting compiler optimizations.

(Note my interest in this question is mostly curiosity to understand what `volatile` does rather than to solve any specific problem.)

(Also I have marked this question as both C and C++ not because I think they are the same language, but because I am interested to know if there are differences in what `volatile` does in this case in these two languages).

Comment: You have a function returning a `volatile int`, not a volatile function.

Comment: I don't think this is really a *duplicate* and the close is incorrect, but whatever. An important distinction in C++ is `volatile` member functions. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826719/c-volatile-member-functions

Comment: Take a look on http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766

Comment: @user1929959 : _Extremely_ outdated...

Comment: @ildjarn Not fallen to think that if a post is old then it is useful. Volatile function is not new.

Comment: @ildjarn: That is an interesting point of view, specially considering that while written in 2001 it is more *current* now with all of the threading focus than it was when it was published. If you have any concerns other than *it's old* I invite you to treat them in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491495/may-volatile-be-in-user-defined-types-to-help-writing-thread-safe-code)

Comment: @user1929959 : The point is that `volatile` is _not_ a multithreaded programmer's best friend – `std::atomic<>` is.

Comment: @ildjarn Don't consider c11 as be most used standard, is just experimental.

Comment: @user1929959 : In that case there's [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/libs/atomic/). ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your code, the `volatile` keyword does not apply to the function, but to the return type, it is the equivalent of:

```
typedef volatile int Type;
Type foo();
```

Now, in C++ you can make a *member* function `volatile`, in the same way that the `const` qualifier, and the behavior is the same:

```
struct test {
   void vfunction() volatile;
};
```

Basically you cannot call a non-volatile (alterantively non-const) function on a volatile (const respectively) instance of the type:

```
struct test {
   void vfunction() volatile;
   void function();
};
volatile test t;
t.vfunction();      // ok
t.function();       // error
```

Answer (score 6):

`foo()` is not volatile.

It's a function that returns a `volatile int`.

Which is legal.  But strange for a returned `int`.

Member functions, on the other hand, can be `volatile` for the same reason they can be `const` -- both describe the object `this` is pointing to.

Comment: +1, specially for the comment *But strange for a returned `int`*. As a matter of fact the compiler is free to drop the `volatile` qualifier from the returned object.

Comment: that's the question, what's a "volatile int"???  saying it's a "volatile int" doesn't answer what a "volatile int" is. we know making an int variable volatile means no optimization. what optimization could you logically need to prevent from a function? an rvalue (temp) is already optimized. it seems completely useless.

Comment: @Puddle nowhere in this question is the phrase "what's a volatile int".  This question is asking "What does the keyword volatile do when applied to a **function**".  Perhaps you have a different question to ask here?

Comment: @DrewDormann you said it yourself "Which is legal. But strange for a returned int." why's it strange? don't you understand it? when would you need to prevent optimization on a function? that's entirely why this question is being asked. anything strangely related could be relevant to answering the question. by "volatile int" you know i was referring to the example. are you saying "volatile rvalue"? if so how does that work? as if it's doing this? int x = (volatile)5;